# Is it possible to expose a function defined within a React function component to be called in other components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, react-state-management

I'm refactoring some old code for an alert widget and am abstracting it into its own component that uses DOM portals and conditional rendering. I want to keep as much of the work inside of this component as I possibly can, so ideally I'd love to be able to expose the Alert component itself as well as a function defined inside of that component triggers the render state and style animations so that no outside state management is required. Something like this is what I'm looking to do:

```
import Alert, { renderAlert } from '../Alert'

const CopyButton = () => (
  <>
    <Alert text="Text copied!" />
    <button onClick={() => renderAlert()}>Copy Your Text</button>
  </>
)
```

Here's what I currently have for the Alert component - right now it takes in a state variable from outside that just flips when the button is clicked and triggers the `useEffect` inside of the Alert to trigger the `renderAlert` function. I'd love to just expose `renderAlert` directly from the component so I can call it without the additional state variable like above.

```
const Alert = ({ label, color, stateTrigger }) => {
  const { Alert__Container, Alert, open } = styles;

  const [alertVisible, setAlertVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [alertRendered, setAlertRendered] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const portalElement = document.getElementById('portal');

  const renderAlert = (): void => {
    setAlertRendered(false);
    setAlertVisible(false);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlertVisible(true);
    }, 5);
    setAlertRendered(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setAlertRendered(false);
      }, 251);
      setAlertVisible(false);
    }, 3000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    renderAlert();
  }, [stateTrigger])

  const ele = (
    <div className={Alert__Container}>
      { alertRendered && (
        <div className={`${Alert} ${alertVisible ? open : ''}`}>
          <DesignLibAlert label={label} color={color}/>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );

  return portalElement
    ? ReactDOM.createPortal(ele, portalElement) : null;
};

export default Alert;
```

Comment: I think you're not thinking in react. https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html you should not expose functions of components. Instead pass props to control a components state.

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann In this case passing all of the state in as props means repeating the necessary code across any component that needs to render an alert so that I can then pass it in, which is not ideal because it makes the codebase very un-DRY. I'd love to keep as much of this functionality internal as possible so all of that state and logic lives in one place - the component that uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it's not common to "reach" into other components and invoke functions, React does allow a "backdoor" to do so.

- [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)
- [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref)

The idea is to expose out the `renderAlert` function imperatively via the React ref system.

Example:

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const Alert = forwardRef(({ label, color, stateTrigger }, ref) => {
  const { Alert__Container, Alert, open } = styles;

  const [alertVisible, setAlertVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [alertRendered, setAlertRendered] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const portalElement = document.getElementById('portal');

  const renderAlert = (): void => {
    setAlertRendered(false);
    setAlertVisible(false);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlertVisible(true);
    }, 5);
    setAlertRendered(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setAlertRendered(false);
      }, 251);
      setAlertVisible(false);
    }, 3000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    renderAlert();
  }, [stateTrigger]);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    renderAlert,
  }));

  const ele = (
    <div className={Alert__Container}>
      { alertRendered && (
        <div className={`${Alert} ${alertVisible ? open : ''}`}>
          <DesignLibAlert label={label} color={color}/>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );

  return portalElement
    ? ReactDOM.createPortal(ele, portalElement) : null;
});

export default Alert;
```

...

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import Alert from '../Alert'

const CopyButton = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  const clickHandler = () => {
    ref.current?.renderAlert();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Alert ref={ref} text="Text copied!" />
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Copy Your Text</button>
    </>
  )
};
```

[image: Edit is-it-possible-to-expose-a-function-defined-within-a-react-function-component-to]

A more React-way to accomplish this might be to abstract the Alert state into an AlertProvider that renders the portal and handles the rendering of the alert and provides the `renderAlert` function via the context.

Example:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

interface I_Alert {
  renderAlert: (text: string) => void;
}

const AlertContext = createContext<I_Alert>({
  renderAlert: () => {}
});

const useAlert = () => useContext(AlertContext);

const AlertProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactElement }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>("");
  const [alertVisible, setAlertVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [alertRendered, setAlertRendered] = useState<boolean>(false);

  ...

  const renderAlert = (text: string): void => {
    setAlertRendered(false);
    setAlertVisible(false);
    setText(text);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlertVisible(true);
    }, 5);
    setAlertRendered(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setAlertRendered(false);
      }, 251);
      setAlertVisible(false);
    }, 3000);
  };

  const ele = <div>{alertRendered && <div> ..... </div>}</div>;

  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={{ renderAlert }}>
      {children}
      // ... portal ...
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

...

```
const CopyButton = () => {
  const { renderAlert } = useAlert();

  const clickHandler = () => {
    renderAlert("Text copied!");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Copy Your Text</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AlertProvider>
      ...
      <div className="App">
        ...
        <CopyButton />
        ...
      </div>
      ...
    </AlertProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit is-it-possible-to-expose-a-function-defined-within-a-react-function-component-to (forked)]